# Parse attribute-centric XML with missing tags in R

Tags: r, xml

I have an XML file like this

```
<deviations-hour date-hour="2019052403" i-point="1.12291" price-up="1.12291" price-down="1.06395">
    <deviations deviation-type="46" deviation-price="1.12290" deviation-power="138.000">
    </deviations>
</deviations-hour>
<deviations-hour date-hour="2019052404" i-point="1.16397" price-up="1.16397" price-down="1.10773">
    <deviations deviation-type="45" deviation-price="1.10774" deviation-power="-685.000">
    </deviations>
</deviations-hour>
    <deviations-hour date-hour="2019052405" i-point="1.32412" price-up="1.32412" price-down="1.12999">
</deviations-hour>
<deviations-hour date-hour="2019052406" i-point="1.18508" price-up="1.18508" price-down="1.14266">
    <deviations deviation-type="45" deviation-price="1.14266" deviation-power="-214.000">
    </deviations>
</deviations-hour>
```

I tried to read file into dataframe.

```
library("XML")
doc <- xmlParse(xmlfile)
partA <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, path='//deviations-hour'))
partB <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, path='//deviations'))
```

`xmlAttrsToDataFrame` works fine. But.. Some lines of `deviations` tags are missing in XML file, but dataframe partB does not contain NAs. The function just skips these lines.
Eventually partB does not contain the same number of lines as partA, and I cannot correctly merge them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first go using the `xml2` packagens and the `tidyverse`.

I included a lot of comments to clarify each step taken.

```
library( xml2 )
library( tidyverse )

#read xml
doc <- xml2::read_xml( "./test.xml" )

#get the deviation-hour/deviation nodes
devHr.nodes <- xml2::xml_find_all( doc, ".//deviations-hour")
dev.nodes   <- xml2::xml_find_all( doc, ".//deviations")

#create vector all (unique) attrubutes inside deviations-hour/deviation nodes
att.devHr <- xml2::xml_attrs(devHr.nodes) %>% lapply( names ) %>% unlist() %>% unique()
att.dev   <- xml2::xml_attrs(dev.nodes)   %>% lapply( names ) %>% unlist() %>% unique()

#build part A
partA <- 
  #loop over the attributes, extract attribute-values from all devHr.nodes
  lapply( att.devHr, function(x) devHr.nodes %>% xml_attr(x) ) %>% 
  #set column names
  set_names( att.devHr ) %>% 
  #convert to data.frame
  as.data.frame()

#build part B
partB <- 
  #loop over the attributes, extract attribute-values from all devHr.nodes
  lapply( att.dev, function(x) dev.nodes %>% xml_attr(x) ) %>% 
  #set column names
  set_names( att.dev ) %>% 
  #convert to data.frame
  as.data.frame() %>%
  #find the parent node's date-time attribute, and extract it's value
  mutate( date.hour = xml_find_first( dev.nodes , ".//parent::deviations-hour") %>% xml_attr("date-hour") )

#left join on the timestamp
left_join( partA, partB, by = "date.hour")
```

**output**

```
#    date.hour i.point price.up price.down deviation.type deviation.price deviation.power
# 1 2019052403 1.12291  1.12291    1.06395             46         1.12290         138.000
# 2 2019052404 1.16397  1.16397    1.10773             45         1.10774        -685.000
# 3 2019052405 1.32412  1.32412    1.12999           <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
# 4 2019052406 1.18508  1.18508    1.14266             45         1.14266        -214.000
```

**sample data "./test.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <deviations-hour date-hour="2019052403" i-point="1.12291" price-up="1.12291" price-down="1.06395">
        <deviations deviation-type="46" deviation-price="1.12290" deviation-power="138.000">
        </deviations>
    </deviations-hour>
    <deviations-hour date-hour="2019052404" i-point="1.16397" price-up="1.16397" price-down="1.10773">
        <deviations deviation-type="45" deviation-price="1.10774" deviation-power="-685.000">
        </deviations>
    </deviations-hour>
        <deviations-hour date-hour="2019052405" i-point="1.32412" price-up="1.32412" price-down="1.12999">
    </deviations-hour>
    <deviations-hour date-hour="2019052406" i-point="1.18508" price-up="1.18508" price-down="1.14266">
        <deviations deviation-type="45" deviation-price="1.14266" deviation-power="-214.000">
        </deviations>
    </deviations-hour>
</data>
```